# How to use cv_camera with IP cameras?

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am trying to use cv_camera with an IP camera. I am not sure how to initialize cv_camera such that it can read a cv_camera.

My understanding is that this would be done through setting the 'device_id' parameter. However, when I tried to set it to an http stream, it activated my laptop camera instead.

I did more experimenting and discovered that device_id only worked if it was set to an integer. I thought that the device_id parameter was passed to an instance of Videocapture cap(device_id) but this does not seem to be the case. I tried calling the address of an attached webcam directly '/dev/video1' but that did not work. I experimented with different cv paths as specified here:

http://funvision.blogspot.ca/2017/06/opencv-reading-ip-camera-video-stream.html

but I haven't been able to get anything besides integer inputs to device_id to work.

Any assistance or insight would be appreciated. Thank you for your time.

EDIT: There is another parameter called device_path that is documented on the github page.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/288833/how-to-use-cv_camera-with-ip-cameras?/) by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-04-16

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-17**:
Please post your resolution as an answer and then accept your own answer.

We rarely close questions here on ROS Answers when they are answered.

**Comment by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) on 2018-04-25**:
Thanks for letting me know, but unfortunately I do not have sufficient karma to accept my own answer.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-04-25**:
I've just accepted it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is another parameter called device_path that is documented on the github page. This allows you to specify a cv_stream.

---

Originally posted by [Coppermind](https://answers.ros.org/users/34294/coppermind/) with karma: 30 on 2018-04-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0